# 'x' and 'w' must have same length - error in weighted.mean.default

Tags: r, glmnet

I am having a problem with the package `glmnet` in R. I am trying to use it off-the-shelf, and am getting the following problem:

```
test <- glmnet(seq.trans,rsem.trans)
```

> Error in weighted.mean.default(y, weights) :
>         'x' and 'w' must have the same length

But the inputs are the same size:

```
dim(seq.trans)
# [1]    28 17763
dim(rsem.trans)
# [1]    28 17763
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: `y` should be a vector, not a matrix. `rsem.trans` is your `y` and it is a matrix.

Comment: Yup, that solved my problem.

Comment: It hasn't solved mine.  I tried applying `as.vector(y)` but still get the same problem.  If I apply `c(y)` I get a different error from `cv.glmnet`:  *number of observations in y (1) not equal to the number of rows of x (42)*

Comment: Ok, got it: `as.numeric(unlist(y))`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but found the solution was that both X and y should be matrices. I was running the code below without the `as.matrix` function and getting the same error. Then I tried this and it worked. Also see the example in [this tutorial](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) by loading the data that should come in the package, and you'll see that both x and y in the first example are both matrices.

```
library(glmnet)
library(dplyr)
X <- as.matrix(select(mtcars, -mpg))
y <- as.matrix(select(mtcars, mpg))

fit <- glmnet(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of `glmnet(x,y)` the variable `y` should be a vector.

In your example, you could achieve this using:

```
glmnet(seq.trans, as.vector(rsem.trans))
```